# buttons around the node

Tags: neo4j, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm wondering if there is a way in vis.js to show buttons around the active node exactly like neo4j browser. I mean something like the screenshot (you can see 3 grey buttons). I searched around I found nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is only possible by direct implementation, no helpers inside vis.js itself (aside the `click` event and coordinate getting) – you have to implement the menu elements and their handlers from the network's canvas object.